# Jekyll Liquid Exception: Cannot find /bin/sh on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, jekyll, railsinstaller

I installed the Jekyll Gem on Windows via a Ruby installation using the RailsInstaller distribution.

When I try to run `jekyll build` or any command that includes that as a subcommand, I get the following error:

[image: Jekyll error]

`2013-03-08-response-ruby-interfaces.md` is one of my posts.  Any suggestions as to what might be going on?  The command builds out the skeleton of the site, in the `_site` directory, but all of the files are empty.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it build when you remove that post? If so, add a link to Markdown file, problem should be there.

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this issue as well and solved it by turning pygments off in my _config.yml:

```
pygments:    false
```

Despite having pygments installed, I can't seem to get it to work with Jekyll under Windows.

You lose syntax highlighting, but you gain a working Jekyll install.

Comment: No such luck for me; still getting the same issue.

Comment: seems like downgrading pygments helps as well. This SO details it in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17404260/50109

Comment: This fixes the issue for now. I tried installing pygments, not sure still not working. Better disable for now and get back to work.

Comment: Genius. Works like a charm. Thanks for making an SO account just to answer this.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to fix doing two things

First is making sure that pygments is running on 0.5.0. At the same time making sure that newer versions are uninstalled

```
gem uninstall pygments.rb --version "=0.5.2"
gem uninstall pygments.rb --version "=0.5.1"
gem install pygments.rb --version "=0.5.0"
```

Second, well, pygments would need python installed and adding it in

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\setup_environment.bat
```

At this line

```
SET PATH=%RUBY_DIR%\bin;other paths\here;%PATH%
```

Will become

```
SET PATH=%RUBY_DIR%\bin;other paths\here;C:\Python27;%PATH%
```

Close the "Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails" and start again. It will now run **jekyll serve** without errors

Reference:

[Jekyll on Windows: Pygments not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364028/jekyll-on-windows-pygments-not-working/17404260)

Comment: `
gem uninstall pygments.rb --version "=0.5.2"
gem uninstall pygments.rb --version "=0.5.1"
gem install pygments.rb --version "=0.5.0"`

does the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was the same and changing the encode solve
Use UTF8

Comment: that just removes the Liquid exception but then Jekyll for some reason completely ignores the file

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Mon Noval's answer, I would also make sure you run `gem list` first and look for pygments.  I followed Mon Noval's process, and when it still didn't fix things, I ran `gem list` in the command line and found out that I did have `pygments 0.5.0` installed but in the parentheses it was also showing `0.5.4` installed.  So make sure you look for any and all versions above `0.5.0`!

Works like a charm now!